# R read and plot gdbtable

Tags: r

I'm very new to gbd table and today at work I was asked to use R to read the data available on https://frap.fire.ca.gov/media/9792/fthrt14_2.zip and plot it using R tools like ggplot and plot_ly.
My problem is that I don't even understand how to read this data with R.
These are the stackoverflow questions I read so far:
 - [rgdal - read a table within a ESRI geodatabase (gdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732055/rgdal-read-a-table-within-a-esri-geodatabase-gdb)
 - [How to read a table from an ESRI file geodatabase (.gdb) using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705217/how-to-read-a-table-from-an-esri-file-geodatabase-gdb-using-r)
 - [How do I get rgdal to open a geodatabase (.gdb) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910398/how-do-i-get-rgdal-to-open-a-geodatabase-gdb-file)
however none of them seems to be working.
These are my steps:
 - I unzipped the file in my C:\temp folder. This means I have an R variable `file_gdb = "C:/temp/fthrt14_2.gdb"`
 - then, I have `fc_list = ogrListLayers(file_gdb )` and if I print its content I see:

```
character(0)
attr(,"driver")
[1] "OpenFileGDB"
attr(,"nlayers")
[1] 0
```

- at this point I try `fc = readOGR(dsn=fgdb,layer="OpenFileGDB")` but I get the following error:

  Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv
  Cannot open layer

and from here I'm quite lost.
Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks from a complete newbie.

Comment: That a zip file. It does have severak gdb files in the zip archive, but you first need to expand it and then work on them separately.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184013/read-a-table-from-an-esri-file-geodatabase-gdb-using-r